# CreateFile error trying to open pipe

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to create a demonstration client/server application using named pipes on two Windows 7 machines, but cannot get this to work. The two machines, let's call them server and laptop, are both connected to an ethernet switch which is in turn connected to a cable modem.  Both machines can see the internet, and both machines show up in the Windows network map. So I think they are correctly networked.

I am writing in Visual C++ and am basically copying the sample code on MSDN for a named pipe server and client.  On my server, I call CreateNamedPipe() using the pipe name:

```
\\.\pipe\MyServerName
```

On the client, I call CreateFile with the pipe name of:

```
\\<machine>\pipe\MyServerName
```

where "machine" is configurable.  If I run the server and client on the same machine, and for machine use either "." or "POWEREDGE" (the name of my server machine according to Windows), the two programs communicate fine.

Now I go to my laptop and run the client software.  I use "POWEREDGE" as the machine name. CreateFile fails with GetLastError=1 ("Incorrect Function" apparently).

Any ideas about what could be going wrong here?

In response to requests, here is the actual code:

```
 // CLIENT SIDE
 // note: value of gLKServer is "POWEREDGE"
 char PipeName[256]="";
 wsprintf(PipeName,"\\\\%s\\pipe\\LKServer", gLKServerName);

 while (TRUE) {
   hPipe = CreateFile( 
   PipeName,   // pipe name 
   GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
   GENERIC_WRITE, 
   0,              // no sharing 
   NULL,           // default security attributes
   OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
   0,              // default attributes 
   NULL);          // no template file 

   if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
     break; 
   }

   // Exit if an error other than ERROR_PIPE_BUSY occurs. 

   if (err=GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY) 
    {
      printf("CreateFile error %lu\n", err); 
    }
    ...

 // SERVER SIDE
 char PipeName[256]="\\\\.\\pipe\\LKServer"; 
  hPipe = CreateNamedPipe( 
      PipeName,             // pipe name 
      PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
      PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
      PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
      PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
      PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
      BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
      BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
      0,                        // client time-out 
      NULL);                    // default security attribute
```

Comment: Tried to disable windows firewall?

Comment: I have Kaspersky, but I did try disabling it and there was no difference.

Comment: Please show your actual code. You are most likely not formatting the pipe name correctly.

Comment: Does `ping POWEREDGE` work on the command line (on the client)?  Is there a delay before the CreateFile call fails, or does it fail instantly?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Ping works.  The CreateFile fails almost immediately, 15 milliseconds.  I have added code to my original post to show to CreateFile and CreateNamedPipe calls.

Comment: If GetLastError() returns 1 then your error checking is broken.  A *very* common bug.  This is not youtube.com, you have to show us.

Comment: OK you are right - not sure why err=GetLastError() inside an If statement messes up, but if I break it out I learn that the error is actually 1326, something to do with logon failure.  Obviously I don't know what I'm doing with networking - can anybody enlighten me about how I gain the credentials needed for one Windows machine to open a pipe to another?

Comment: I think it should work if the username and password is the same on the remote machine as on the local machine.  Failing that you might have to establish a network connection to the remote machine first, e.g., using WNetAddConnection2.  (If you establish a connection to \\POWEREDGE\IPC$ then when you open the pipe it should use the existing connection automatically.)

Comment: Right now my theory is that the last parameter to CreateNamedPipe on the server, which is the security attribute, needs to be modified.  Documentation says the default value of null creates a pipe that grants read access to the everyone group and anonymous account.  Not sure what that means - any further advice would be appreciated.